# Кириллица в Post-запросе HttpUrlConnection

Tags: php, java, post

В Java-проекте отправляется post-запрос, с помощью которого редактируется некоторая бд.

```
HttpURLConnection connection;
String params = "a=save&str=" + str + "&table=" + table;
URL url = new URL(Program.site + "save.php");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "ru-RU");
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.connect();
try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())) {
     dos.writeBytes(params);
     dos.flush();
}
...
```

Проблема в том, что кириллица передается неправильно, например, "ыыы" заменится на "KKK". Если в указанном save.php меняю автоматически то, что должно браться из post, на кириллицу, всё нормально. В php:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: а сам php тоже сохранён в utf-8?

Comment: а в котором месте задается кодировка строки? _str_ и _table_? У них точно UTF-8? А у строки _params_ точно UTF-8? То, что вы хедер запроса выставили в данную кодировку, еще не значит, то в этой кодировке информацию отправляете.

Comment: Как перевести кодировку строки java в utf-8? а сам файл да, в utf-8